# Scaling down Bitmaps in ImageButtons to avoid OutOfMemory

Tags: java, android, button, bitmap, out-of-memory

i have here some ImageButtons

```
 ImageButton btn_start = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
 ImageButton btn_start.setOnClickListener(this);
 ImageButton btn_start2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_start2);
 ImageButton btn_start2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and want to scale their picture in it, to avoid OutOfMemory.

I've tried this, by using [THIS](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html), but it isn't working, means, the application ends with an OutOfMemory (my MainScreen.java):

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.imageView1, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
String imageType = options.outMimeType;


BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btn_start, options);
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btn_start2, options);

btn_start.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.id.btn_start2));

btn_start2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.id.btn_start3));
```

**Update**

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.imageView1, options);
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
    String imageType = options.outMimeType;
     //options.inSampleSize=calculateInSampleSize(options,imageHeight,imageWidth);


    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.start2, options);
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.start1, options);

     btn_start.setImageBitmap( BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.start1, options)); 
    btn_start2.setImageBitmap(
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.start2, options)); 
}


    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }
 }
```

I've tried to put everything needed in my code, but no results so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void setupLogo(){
  Bitmap bmp = createBitmap();
  //YOU CAN CHANGE THIS TO A BUTTON, AND SET IMAGE FOR THE BUTTON
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) R.id.imageViewFromLayout;
  imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}

public Bitmap createBitmap(){

 BitmapFactory.Options options2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();                      
 options2.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
 //YOU CAN CHANGE THIS TO DECODE RESOURCE
 BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Main.this.getExternalFilesDir(filepath) +"/companylogo.png",options2);
 options2.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize();//=32
 options2.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
 //YOU CAN CHANGE THIS TO DECODE RESOURCE
 return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Main.this.getExternalFilesDir(filepath) +"/companylogo.png",options2);
}

public int calculateInSampleSize() {

 DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = Main.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
 int reqWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
 //WILL OUTPUT THE IMAGE AT 100x100 PIXELS                      
 final int height = 100;
 final int width = 100;

 double devCal2 =  (height*1000)/width;
 int reqHeight = (int) ((devCal2/1000)*reqWidth); 

 int inSampleSize = 1;

 if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

  final int halfHeight = height / 2;
  final int halfWidth = width / 2;

  // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
  // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
  while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
   inSampleSize *= 2;
  }
 }
 return inSampleSize;
}
```

Call setupLogo(); to setup the bmp and then assign it to the ImageView or button

Comment: how do I set the scale if I want for little screens a little resolution, and for big screens a big resolution?

Comment: You need to use the insample size. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: yes, and after that, I have to tell the bitmap how large it has to be as you mentioned in your first comment. may you have a look at my updated question, I dont know, do I have to use the insample size on every picture new or what do I have to do, because i think I can't just copy the sample like I did now..?

Comment: I think you use options.inSampleSize=calculateInSampleSize(height,width);

Comment: so I added this line in the code as you can see in my updated question now: options.inSampleSize=calculateInSampleSize(options,imageHeight,imageWidth);  but I'm still getting the error..?

Comment: Try this;

    btn_start.setImageBitmap( BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btn_start, options));

    btn_start2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btn_start2, options));
}

Comment: Your using different resource when setting the bitmap, which must also be to big

Comment: I've putted this in my code, nothing changed...it's like my app ignores the bitmap scaling (question updated). what does it mean for me when you say my different resource must be to big?

Comment: Pls, I went a few steps back, and went from there, and since then it seems working fine, i've found another error, for the int (height,width) I'm receiving 0 ...why?

Comment: I think you need to use the inHeight and inWidth

Comment: If you can wait till monday then i will give u a working example. But theyre all over the net for scaling bitmaps. You are decoding btn_start but using btn_start1 on your button. You dont need the imageHeight and width. You need to pass the required height and width to calculateinsamplesize

Comment: how to get the inHeight?  i get 0 for height if i run my app in debug mode. yes I saw it with the different drawables,  but it's fine,  in my code its correct,  i'll update the question according to my code in a few hours-when i'm back from work

Comment: I have updated  my question, I think I'm decoding my ressource before it actually knows what the inSampleSize is?

Comment: Thanks @matty357. I appreciate your effort for helping. If you think my question contributes towards SO, please consider to upvote it!